# PayPal Express Checkout - Adding postage options dependent on location

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I use paypal express checkout on my website which adds specific postage amounts dependent on how much is spent by the client wherever they are in the world. However with the recent increase in overseas postage I am looking to add another postage amount dependent on where in the world the client is?
Many thanks in advance
Steve

Comment: From your wording, it sounds like you are wanting to set up postage based on two inputs: location and order amount. To my knowledge, you can only set it up based on one variable at a time (weight, amount, location, etc.)

Comment: Many thanks for your input, you are right, only one variable BUT i do not think 'location' is one of them? Just looks like cost and weight? Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express Checkout, you could utilize the Callback API to calculate the shipping and taxes and have it correctly displayed on the checkout page.  Your server would be performing the calculations and then sending it over to PayPal to update the checkout page based on what shipping address they select from their PayPal account.  Some merchants will even tie this in with other API's through 3rd party shipping to get accurate shipping charges.  You can find more on the Callback API in the [Developers Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf), on page 55.  And there is some information [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/callback-api-operation-nvp) as well.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I will certainly take a look at the links you posted. Much appreciated :-)